# Wie sagt man "I saw him running" oder ähnliche Sätze?

Tags: grammar, translation, sentence-structure

Ich habe mich oft gefragt, wie man das englische Konstrukt *"I saw him running"* im Allgemeinen übersetzen soll, habe aber noch niemanden gefragt. Wenn ich das Antwort raten müsste, würde ich es vielleicht mit *"Ich habe ihn rennen gesehen"* übersetzen, aber ich bin mir unsicher. Wäre das richtig, oder habe ich mich vergaloppiert?

Und wenn das richtig ist, was mit den Fällen *"I found him trying to catch a pig"* und *"I saw her walking to school"?* Sind sie mit *"Ich hab ihn ein Schwein fangen versuchen gefunden"* und bzw. *"Ich sah sie zur Schule gehen"* zu übersetzen? (Die letzte Übersetzung klingt für mich falsch: ich würde lieber *"Ich sah sie, als sie in die Schule ging"* sagen. Ich könnte auch mit den beiden falsch liegen! :D)

Comment: Wenn mein Deutsch ganz unverstehbar ist, dann kann ich auch die Frage auf Englisch schreiben, und ihr könnt mir vielleicht helfen, das Deutsche zu korrigieren! :)

Comment: Dein Deutsch ist ganz wunderbar zu verstehen! Im Österreichischen, wie ich es kenne, werden alle deine Konstellationen mit sehen sowohl in der gesprochenen als auch in der geschriebenen Sprache benutzt - allerdings so gut wie immer im Perfekt, nicht im Präteritum, was in der Natur der österreichischen Sprache liegt. Eine geeignete [kurze und prägnante] Übersetzung für _"I found him/her"_ habe ich bis jetzt auch noch nicht gefunden...

Comment: @jera Danke! user unknown hat dabei geholfen ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bei Verben der Wahrnehmung ist der Infinitiv (ohne *zu*) durchaus üblich:

> Ich höre das Gras wachsen.
>
> Ich sehe die Katastrophe kommen.
>
> Ich spüre mein Herz klopfen.
>
> Ich fühle die Kälte emporsteigen.
>
> Eher nicht: *Ich rieche die Milch anbrennen. (Warum eigentlich nicht?)

Das Perfekt wird hier aber manchmal — genau wie bei Modalverben — mit *haben* + **Infinitiv** gebildet:

> Ich habe das Gras wachsen **hören**.
>
> Ich habe die Katastrophe kommen **sehen**.
>
> Aber: Ich habe die Kälte emporsteigen gefühlt.
>
> Aber: Ich habe mein Herz klopfen gespürt.
>
> Und wenn schon: *Ich habe die Milch anbrennen gerochen.

Ganz anders steht es mit der Übersetzung von „I found him doing s.th.“ im Sinne von „bei/während einer Tätigkeit vorfinden/antreffen“. Ich kenne kein deutsches Wort, das hier ein näheres Objekt erlaubt. Damit ist ein Infinitiv praktisch ausgeschlossen. Bestenfalls passt hier noch ein Partizip:

> Ich fand ihn auf dem Sofa schlafend (vor).
>
> Ich traf ihn Schweine jagend (an).

Diese Form ist aber (leider) für viele Verben veraltet. Und sobald die Tätigkeit etwas ausgeschmückt wird, verwendet man immer einen Nebensatz mit *als*, *wie* oder *während*.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Es tut mir leid, aber ich verstehe noch nicht, wieso man das Bespiel mit der Milch eigentlich nicht sagen soll. Und wie soll man wissen, ob das "haben + Infinitiv" Konstrukt zu benutzen ist? Ist das nur ein Gefühl, das entwickelt werden muss?

Comment: Es besteht oft sowohl die Option, den Nebensatz durch einen Substantiv zu ersetzen.  zB "Ich habe ihn auf der Schweinejagd / beim Schweinejagen gesehen."

Answer (score 3):

"Ich habe ihn rennen gesehen" wäre "I have seen him running", also ist "I saw him running" mit "Ich sah ihn laufen/rennen" passender übersetzt.

> I found him trying to catch a pig.

hält eine Falle bereit, weil *found* wörtlich übersetzt mit *fand* zu übersetzten wäre, aber keine gängige Phrase in solchen Situationen ist. Hier ist *antreffen* üblicher.

`Ich traf ihn an, wie er ein Schwein zu fangen versuchte.`

In seltenen Fällen geht auch 'fand', etwa

```
Ich fand meinen Onkel besoffen am Küchenboden vor.  
Ich fand meine Frau, nackt im Bett mit dem Nachbarn.
```

Nicht zwingend wird eine Suche vorrausgesetzt, aber eine Überraschung müsste dabei sein.

> I saw her walking to school.

```
Ich sah sie zur Schule gehen.
```

Comment: Also, "finden" benötigt, daß jemand sucht, und "antreffen" ist näher zu meiner Benutzung vom englischen Wort "find"?

Comment: Und man soll "wie er ..." sagen, statt "während" oder "als"?

Comment: 'Finden' erfordert nicht zwingend, dass eine Suche vorrausgeht, aber meist wird es so verwendet. 'Ich fand meinen Autoschlüssel unter der Zeitung.' Da mir der Kontext zur Schweineepisode fehlt kann ich wenig dazu sagen, aber in vielen Fällen, wo der Engländer 'I found Joe Doe ...ing some foobar' sagt, sagt der Deutsche 'Ich traf Hr. Müller an, Ypsylon ixen.'  Man begegnet einer Person und beschreibt, was diese in dem Moment tut.

Comment: 'Während' und 'als' würde ich wählen, wenn die Aussage wäre 'I found him while he was trying ...' oder 'when he was...'.

Comment: Ich wüsste gerne, warum du einen Unterschied zwischen Perfekt und Präteritum im Deutschen zu konstruieren versuchst; warum also das Präteritum hier passender sein soll. Die Grammatik der Ursprungssprache hat in der Übersetzung nichts verloren.